# My inherited class MenuBar(tk.Menu) does not showing Menubar

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, tkinter, menu

I have been trying to add a main menu to my program and am having trouble with it.
I don't exactly understand the class structure of python3 as I'm fairly new to programming with it. 
I am running on ubuntu 18.04 and here is the code I am having trouble with.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

class Application(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.config(menu=menubar)

    def quitButton(self):
        self.destroy()

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = parent

        menubar = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Test", command=self.test_Test)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda:    self.controller.quitButton())
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    def test_Test(self):
        print("This is a test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.title("test") 
    app.mainloop()
```

The file menu does not appear for me. Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Question**: tkinter ... not showing Main Menu

There are couple problems here.

> ```
> class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
>     def __init__(self, parent):
>         tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
>         self.controller = parent
> ```
>
> > Here, you create a **new** `tk.Menu(...` with parent == `self`.
> >     The Variable `menubar` hold the `tk.Menu(...` object.
>
> ```
>     menubar = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
> ```
>
> A `class __init__` methode returns itself, therefore you **don't** return the new `menubar`.
>   You return a `class MenuBar(tk.Menu)` object, which ist **empty**!

change to

```
class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
```

- Your `class MenuBar` **is** the new menubar! Therefore, the **init** parameters goes here

  ```
      tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent, tearoff=False)
  ```
- The submenus `parent` is this class, therefore pass `self`.

  ```
      filemenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
  ```
- Add `filemenu` items as used

  ```
      filemenu.add_command(label="Test", command=self.test_Test)
      filemenu.add_separator()
      filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=lambda: self.controller.quitButton())
  ```
- Add the submenu to this object, therefore use `self.add...`.

  ```
      self.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
  ```

---

You can `.config(...` within `class MenuBar` doing:

```
        parent.config(menu=self)
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: Thanks so much. This is like what I figured I was doing wrong. I still have a lot to learn about python. I was easily able to use this advice to fix my program.